# When I change image, useState is not changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, use-state

I have a problem with uploading an image. I have cards and all cards have an image. When I clicked `Update Product`, `Card Details` page is opening.

[image]

After I click this image, I choose another picture, the photo changes in Front, and when I clicked `submit` API gives me success and the correct photo URL.
[image]

But when I submitted this form, I returned all cards page ( with `history.push()`), the image was not changed. If I clicked `empty cache and hard reload` in my browser after the new image was changed. I tried to fix and first of all, I looked `network` and the response gave me the correct link, I opened a new tab and put the link and a new image opened. Maybe the link between old and new images is the same and `useState` is not working.
Api gives a new link, `useState` gives the old link. Both links are the same.

I tried `window.location.reload(true)`, but it did not work first uploading. After first cleaning the cache, the image was uploaded, and after the second uploading, it worked without cleaning the cache.

My codes

It is for getting one card's data and image

```
 const [getPhoto, setGetPhoto] = useState();

 useQuery(["PRODUCT_DATA_OVERVIEW_BRANCH", id], () => 
  apiService.getAdminProductDetails(id), {
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      setGetPhoto(response.photoUrl);
    },
  });
```

Changing data Api

```
 const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation(apiService.updateAdminProducts, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      enqueueSnackbar("Product was updated", { variant: "success" });
      history.push("/admin/products");
      window.location.reload(true);
    },
  });
```

onSubmit

```
  const onSubmit = () => {
    const urlProductInfo = new URLSearchParams(getProductData);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("photo", getPhoto);
    mutate({ urlProductInfo, formData });
  };
```

api

```
const ApiService = (httpService) => {
   updateAdminProducts: async (variables) => {
      const { urlProductInfo, formData } = variables;
      const response = await httpService.patch(`/product/sme?${urlProductInfo}`, formData);
      return response?.data;
    },
}
```